# Pseudometric from nested sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Assume that $X$ is a nonempty set and that for every $x\in X$ we have a nested family of nonempty sets: $\{E_{x,t}: t\in [0,\infty)\}$ for which $t_1\leq t_2$ implies $E_{x,t_1}\subseteq E_{x,t_2}$, $E_{x,t}\neq\emptyset$ for all $t$. Nothing more is assumed.

Is there always a pseudometric $d$ on $X$ such that for every $x\in X$ and $s>t\geq 0$ we have $E_{x,t}\subseteq \bar{B}(x,t)\subseteq E_{x,s}$, where $\bar{B}(x,t)$ denotes the closed ball with radius $t$ around $x$ in the pseudometric $d$?

If it is always the case please provide proof, if not, please provide appropriate counterexample.

Comment: Where does this come from? What have you tried? It seems very unlikely that this would hold, I'd look for a counterexample.

Comment: Well the trivial pseudometric that just makes every distance 0 satisfies the condition right?

Comment: It is a part of a larger analytical construction I am working on currently. Existence of such a pseudometric would be very helpful. I agree with you that it looks unlikely to hold, however I cannot find counterexample.

Comment: @s.harp Good point,  I have edited my question. Now it looks a bit less trivial :)

Comment: In view of  s.harp"s counter-example  below, I suggest you try adding some more constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample:

let $X= \{x,y\}$ contain only two points. Take $E_{x,t}=\{x\}$ for all $t$ and $E_{y,t}=\{x,y\}$ for all $t$.

Now $\overline{B(x,2)}\subset E_{x,3} =\{x\}$ so if the pseudometric is $d$ then $d(x,y)>2$. But on the other hand $\{x,y\}=E_{y,1}\subset\overline{B(y,1)}$ which necessitates $d(x,y)≤1$.